# Hacer un push a un array dentro de un objeto

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript

Hola tengo un objeto que tiene dentro un array y necesito añadirle una nueva fila al array o quitársela (push y pull) pero no me deja utilizar la funcion push(); el push y pull quiero hacerselo a like. Alguien sabe el porque? Gracias.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5ecaa9ff4a81d100047748e5"
},
"like": [],
"text": "ccv",
"file": "",
"user": {
    "$oid": "5eba909bcec052000419ee35"
},
"date": "2020-05-24T19:08:09.459+02:00, 2020-05-24T19:08:09.458+02:00",
"created_at": "2020-05-24 17:08:15",
"location": "37.8018272,-0.8361596",
"__v": 0
```

}

y esta es la funcion que estoy utilizando para hacerle el push pero me da error.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.publications.length; i++) {
        if (this.publications[i]._id == publication._id) {
          this.publications[i].like.push(this.identity._id)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con el acceso en formato array. Hay veces que Angular no se come el acceso via objeto.

```js
this.publications[i]['like'].push(this.identity._id)
```

Comment: Comparto tu respuesta, aun que creo que la solución seria typar el objeto con una clase asignando a la propiedad like:  Array<any>

Comment: No me a funcionado me dice que "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'"

Comment: Mmm. Parece que el contenido de tu variable no es un array (quizás venga en formato string). Verifica con `Array.isArray(this.publications[i]['like'])`